# Sqlite query to python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have searched the docs and SO and could not find anything to resolve my issue. I am trying to call a select from my sqlite database and add it to a dictionary with the columns as keys. When I do this it returns a row for each column/key. It is has 14 columns and if I only have 4 rows it repeats for each one. This was the first attempt

```
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
results = []
for row in r:
    Summary = {}
    items = zip(columns, row)
    for (items, values) in items:
        Summary[items] = row
        results.append(Summary)
```

Then I also tried the row_factory as given in the docs. That didn't work. My end goal is to be able to print out to a text file verticly by using

```
for x in results:
    print x[name]
    print x[email]
    etc
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your dictionary incorrectly. Use:

```
for row in r:
    summary = dict(zip(columns, row))
    results.append(summary)
```

instead.

Your code sets the whole `row` sequence as the value for each key in `Summary`, instead of the individual column value, then appending that *same* dictionary to the `results` list for each column key..

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple. I am still new at python. I really appreciated your help and that worked perfectly for me.